# How to handle expired Facebook access tokens with SLRequest

Tags: facebook, ios6, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token, acaccount

I've integrated the SLRequest class with my app and can successfully update user timelines etc. So far so good. However, I'm stuck with how to handle the scenario when Facebook invalidates the user's access token (due to inactivity etc).

Normally you'd handle this as per Facebook's advice here : http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/. However on iOS the access token is never set directly by the app, as this is all handled under the hood by the SLRequest  / ACAccount classes.

I've tried re-requesting access to the stored account but this simply gets granted (because as far as iOS is concerned the user has already granted access).

So, other than getting the user to revoke FB for my app and then add it again, is there any way of refreshing the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

renewCredentialsForAccount:completion: of ACAccountStore should be exactly for that, c.f. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011021-CH1-SW19

Comment: Don't know how I didn't see that - RTFM I guess. Thanks!